# A Tale of Two iPhones - One Crashes, One Does Not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

A user of mine reports that when they export a file from my app, the MailComposer appears, and then freezes. At that point, they have to shut down the app completely. They report that waiting an hour does not help. This user is using an iPhone 4, running iOS 6.0.1.

So, I booted the same version of my app, downloaded from the App Store, to an iPhone4 running iOS 6.0.1. When I go to export a file, everything works fine, and I am able to export the track.

Next, I sent him the file I exported, to make sure we were exporting the same file. When he imports the file, and then tries to export it, the same thing happens. Once again, his phone freezes when the MailComposer screen comes up.

I am at a loss for how to debug this problem. What can I do?

**EDIT 2: The user reports that deleting and reinstalling the app corrected the problem. I am still wondering what the underlying issue might be.**

**EDIT: Here is my code:**

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
if (gpsFilePath) {
  [controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:gpsFilePath] mimeType:@"text/gpx" fileName:[self cleanFileName]];
  [controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:kmlFilePath] mimeType:@"text/kml" fileName:[self cleanKMLFileName]];
}
[controller setSubject:subject];
[controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];   
[[MAP_APP_DELEGATE mainController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Get crash logs from the guy or tell him to go home.  We can't do a thing without code.  Voting to close as off topic.  If he hooks his device up to Xcode, he can get device logs.  Or check iTunes Connect to see if any of the crashes are about a ghost process related to MFMailComposeViewController being created by XPC.

Comment: The app doesn't crash, so there are no crash logs. Also, voting to close this questions is ridiculous.

Comment: iOS apps just don't "freeze" for no good reason.  Are you sure you aren't dispatching something incorrectly, or blocking the main thread?  If the application is freezing, it's either a hardware problem, or your application is doing something wonky.  Any application left frozen for an hour should have been killed by the system.

Comment: The fact that none of my many devices, running many iOS versions, crash or freeze makes me think I'm doing things right. The fact that this guy reports a freeze makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's most likely a hardware problem on his end then.  Unless you (or him) can show us a log or some other kind of code, this really isn't a coding problem, it's a localized user problem.

Comment: Are you sure the user's device isn't jailbroken?

Comment: @CodaFi, are you serious?  Ask a user to connect his device to Xcode?    Voting to close this question is ridiculous.  Stack Overflow questions do not have to include code.  Andrew is asking for suggestions on debugging techniques.  That's a software development problem.

Comment: You mention it happens with composer. It could mine an issue with his mail account settings.

Comment: @Nate This question is basically "What the heck is wrong with my App X?"  He has no crash logs to show us, and a persistant user nagging him about an isolated issue which, while serious, is completely up in the air as to what's wrong.  Besides, if you want to get technical and say this is a question about debugging techniques, I'd be happy to point you to a number of duplicate posts so you could close without issue.  What he should do is either get his user to provide him with logs of the problem, or submit a bug report to Apple with the steps the user is reporting freezes his device.

Comment: And that's all well and good, but I've tried it myself, and nothing happens. File a bug report with Apple detailing the steps the user used to reproduce the crash in your application.  @Nate The problem could still, of course, be software related, seeing as MFMailComposeViewController is now an XPC process, but XPC is still a private framework and we can't do anything about that.

Comment: Sounds like something in his email configurations is triggering some bug deep in iOS itself. Have him try sending the same file through the default Mail app, and then create an isolated MFMailComposeViewController app and have him test it there too.

Comment: Have you asked him to totally delete and then reinstall your app?

Comment: Ask him if there's anything unusual about his email config.  Also, is this "freeze" occurring before any touches occur in the mail composer, or does it instead occur after something is touched?  How big is this "attachment" -- could he be running out of storage?

Comment: @CodaFi, if you "want to get technical", the question in a post is what comes before the question mark (`(char)63`).  I'm not sure why you continue to have so many problems with basic reading comprehension, but you do this all the time.  He clearly was asking for recommendations for how to debug a problem.  Describing what was going wrong was context for that question.  His question was not "what the heck is wrong with App X?".  If people knew the answer to *that* question, I'm sure Andrew would have been happy, but the question he posed was about how to go about debugging such a problem.

Comment: @Nate I fail to see why the ad hominem is necessary to explain your point of view.  At the time, I read a question which, to me, was both off topic, and quite honestly, poorly written.  That being my **opinion**, I voted to close as off topic.  If you would like to discuss this further, my email address is listed on my profile, I would be much obliged to discuss the issue with you in a venue that isn't quite so public.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.  If it doesn't crash and just stalls on a certain screen, you may have an infinite loop somewhere.

Here are some avenues I would explore (but most of these assume the user is willing to put a lot of effort into helping you debug this problem, which may be unlikely):

- Is your code above running in the main thread?
- Try smaller or simpler data files, you may be able to isolate certain types of data thats causing this.
- Have the user send you his data, try to repro with that.
- Have the user become one of your beta testers.  You'll have to get his UDID and add it to your provision file.  I recommend using TestFlight to easily get test builds to your beta testers.  They allow you to view crash logs and other useful statistics from your users' sessions.  You can also set "checkpoints" to see how far your user got before the freeze.
- Give that user a build where the attachment functionality is commented out, or various other parts are commented out, to at least pinpoint what is causing the freeze.
- Integrate with the CaptureRecord library, which can make a video recording of your user's experience, so you can actually see what he's seeing.  It saves a video which he can then send to you.  Could give you a better clue as to what's happening.
- If they have a Mac, they can install Xcode, just to use the Organizer for console output which they can send to you.  Otherwise, see next idea.
- In your test build, implement an in-app console that can be saved to a text file on the device.  It can then be fetched using iExplorer, read by the user, and then emailed, or otherwise sent to you.  Basically, implement a wrapper around NSLog which also saves all output to a text file or string, and have it saved to disk, or at least displayable to the user.  This would emulate the console output you would have in Xcode.  You'll probably need an admin interface to be able to turn it on/off, since it may slow down your app.  Make sure you have plenty of debug output in your app.  If it's an infinite loop, you'll see one line repeating forever.  Otherwise, you can at least see what the last line of code was before the freeze.
- Make sure to implement all of the mail composer delegate's functions, and at least log them to console output.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue I had with my App. That app was attaching screen shots to emails. Sometimes they crashed and sometimes they did not. It depended on the device resolution and the resulting size of the image. You may have something similar going on. You have not said enough about what your doing with MailCompose but I solved my problem by wrapping the the bit of code that passed the image to mail composer in an `@autoreleasepool` block. My code is something like this:

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    NSData *img = [self getImageFromChart:chartView];
    [mailController addAttachmentData:img mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"app1.png"];
    img = nil;

    img = [self getImageFromGrid:webView];
    [mailController addAttachmentData:img mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"app2.png"];
    img = nil;
}
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Interesting... I am not using ARC right now, but my next version switched to ARC. I wonder if that would fix it too?

Comment: ARC would not have fixed my issue. It may have actually been related to some kind of iOS bug, I never dug into it that deeply but what I got (and I thought it odd) depending on the device screen resolution was first low memory then crash. The image sizes were just too big for mail to deal with unless in a autorelease pool like that.